# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.status is not a function (NEXT JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

when i console.log(response) then i get the result on the terminal,

but when i use res.status(200).json(response); i get this error on my nextjs project &

> Not Found

on the Browser

```
router.get("/api/backendData", async (req, res, next) => {
  dbConnect();
  try {
    Shop.find().then((response) => {
      res.status(200).json(response);
      response;
      console.log("responseess", response);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error From API Endpoint", e);
  }
});
```

Error code:

> (node:62307) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.status
> is not a function ┃     at
> /home/mh/Documents/Shopiy/shopyy_mode/server/server.js:34:11 ┃
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) ┃
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) ┃ (node:62307) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) ┃ (node:62307) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
> Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
> rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
> with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Seems like res does not have the status function. Are you using expressjs?

Comment: @user2258152 no, i am not using expressjs

Comment: kk so what is the router object or where is it coming from ?

Comment: import Router from "koa-router";
const router = new Router();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koa router does not return (req, res) but a context instead
https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router#router-

```
router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.res.statusCode = 200
  ctx.body = 'your json data'
})
```